# Django Rest Framework: How to show serialized value in django template?

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to show the serialized data in the Django template. I am using Django Rest framework. Using Ajax I have just tried to show the serialized data in a textarea in the html template view.

In view.py, at first, I tried to make a dictionary from a list. And then send it to the serializer.py to make it JSON data. After doing this I just send that serialized data. And from the template, I am using ajax to get this data and set this value in a textarea which is get by ID identifier.

But it does not show the value in the textarea. In the textarea, it just prints "[object Object]". So, how do I show the serialized data in the textarea?

Here is my view.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def result(request):
    text = request.POST['test']
    triples = getTriples(text)

    keys = ['sub','predi','obj']
    demo_data = dict(zip(keys,triples[0]))
    serializer = SentenceListSerializer(data=demo_data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
         serializer.save()
return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      data: {'test': info},
      success: function(response_data){
        $('#textareashow').val(response_data);

      }
    });
```

Comment: You have to iterate the response_data. then you will get the respective result.

Comment: I am trying to do like this `$.each(response_data, function(key, value){
              $('#textareashow').append(key + ":" + value +"\n");` but it shows only the last value. Another question: If the serialized has 2 object value. how to show those using iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify(response_data)`

Inside your ajax success function place this code `$('#textareashow').val(JSON.stringify(response_data));`

Comment: Using JSON.strigify the data is converted to string but I want to show JSON format data. Is it possible?

Comment: sample output:`{
 {
    fisrtname: "xxxx",
    lastname: "yyyy",
    email: "zzz@gmail.com"
 }
 {
    fisrtname: "xxxx",
    lastname: "yyyy",
    email: "zzz@gmail.com"

 }

}`

Comment: You need to iterate over the list and append it. i modified your code from above comment `var data=''; $.each(response_data, function(key, value){ data += key + ":" + value +"\n";} $('#textareashow').append(data);`

Comment: Thank You. It works when I pass only one person information from the view. So, if I want to pass multiple person information from the view, what should I do in view.py?

Comment: You need to pass a queryset to the serializer and set `many=True` ie. `SentenceListSerializer(data=queryset, many=True)`